# Stored procedure in select statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, select

How do I run a stored procedure in a `SELECT` statement ?

For example

```
SELECT
  (<SQL CODE>) A,
  (<SQL CODE>) B
```

I want to run or replace SQL CODE with predefined stored procedures. So how can I run it with in `SELECT` statement ?

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest I know of is `insert ... exec`, like:

```
declare @t1 table (col1 int, col2 varchar(50))
insert @t1 exec ProcA

declare @t2 table (col1 int, col2 varchar(50))
insert @t2 exec ProcB

select  t1.col1
,       t1.col2
,       t2.col1
,       t2.col2
from    @t1 t1
cross join
        @t2 t2
```

The table definition must be exactly the same as the result set of the stored procedure.  Missing columns or slightly different definitions will give an error.