# Stored procedure inside select statement

Tags: sql-server

I want to get a return value of Stored procedure inside a Select statement.
but it was not success.Also i m running
Sp individually it is working fine.
Ex

`DECLARE @ResponseRet VARCHAR(max);
    EXECUTE get_response_by_question_panelistid_sp 6,1,1,117977 , @Response = @ResponseRet OUTPUT
    PRINT @ResponseRet`

But i put them inside select, can not execute them

`SELECT TOP 10 PanelistID, DisplayName,Email,FirstName,LastName,
    EXEC dbo.get_response_by_question_panelistid_sp  6,1,1,117977 as 'Are you …?'
    FROM PFO_Panelists_1`

I can not use function since i am using dynamic table names.

Also tried to execute this SP within function it gives me below error

Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

Any solution ?

Comment: [insert results from SPROC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183142/stored-procedure-in-select-statement) Have a look at that question and the proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in this situation is to create a temporary table and insert values into that table. You can then use the temporary table in your queries.

For example:

```
create procedure testproc
as select 1 as one, 2 as two

go

create table #temp(one int, two int)

insert into #temp
exec testproc

select one, two from #temp
```

Comment: You are correct. But this select statement deals with 100000 add data. Is there any alteration. Such as using dynamic table names inside function. If so it will be really helpfull..

Comment: Hmm, maybe you could use a view?